# Optional prefix for imask

Tags: reactjs, typescript

using react version of this library https://imask.js.org/guide.html

I made hh:mm field using this library

```
export const maskC = 'SH:M';

export const maskObj = {
  S: {
    mask: MaskedEnum,
    enum: ['+', '-'],
  },
  H: {
    mask: MaskedRange,
    from: 0,
    to: 23,
    maxLength: 2,
  },

  M: {
    mask: MaskedRange,
    from: 0,
    to: 59,
    maxLength: 2,
  },
};
```

problem is user have to enter + or - at start
if user want to enter 23:59 they have to type + explicitly at start
what i need is prefix should be optional, what can only be + or -, no other values or special characters

if someone knows the answer, that would be very helpful!

i got to know that we can use this for optional inputs "[]", but this is allowing every character or nuber, what i need is it should only allow + or -, ---> [+-] this won't work

Comment: I need more clarification on your question, can you simplify your question down to "what is your input and what is your desired output?"

Comment: sure so input will be “-“ or nothing at start, followed by two digit number, at this hh:mm field, maximum number can be 23 then “:” and then again two digit number but maximum can be 59 —> desired output should be 12:15 or -12:15 . I hope you’ve understood the question

Comment: Have you solved it? I'm with the same problem!